# Google Search Console cannot read my XML: Sitemap appears to be an HTML page

Tags: seo, google-search-console, sitemap

I'm working on a web application written with AngularJS (v8) and deployed on an apache2 using proxy to forward requests (frontend, api, backoffice).

My problem is that I'm trying to submit the sitemap ({website}/sitemap.xml) on Google, but Google Search Console keep saying that it's not valid: Google can read the link but it seem to be in HTML

[image: gsc]

My sitemap: 
[image: sitemap]

I tried to validate that XML on many website and I didn't find any error.

I mentioned apache2 because maybe when Google try to fetch the URL, before finding the XML, apache give another page but I cannot prove that. I tried in many ways and the first page that I see when opening the URL is the sitemap and nothing else.

In my angular.json I added the file in the assets as follow:

`"assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets", "src/sitemap.xml"],`

What it can be?

Comment: Can you use `curl --head http://example.com/sitemap.xml` from the command line and report what `Content-Type` is returned for your sitemap?

Comment: The screenshot of your sitemap doesn't include the required first line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`, nor does it include required attribute on `urlset`: `<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">`.  I think that is because you have taken a screenshot from a rendered version of it rather than a screenshot of the source code.  Does the source code have these required elements?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller `Content-Type: application/xml`, the first line is included but firefox removed. 
If I check the page content I can clearly see those 2 at first: 
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">`